# Reformat a text file in PHP

Tags: php, file

I want to reformat a text file from this:

```
• Name - 5 September 12:19
- Message
```

To this:

```
Name (5 September, 12:19)
Message
```

Where the names are in **bold** text and it may be some indications that steps forward in the messages (`-- -- -- --`). These indications will be replaces with a `<hr>`. You can see the whole text file [here](http://erik-edgren.nu/files/history/apg29/jesus-september-2014.txt).

I have came up with [this](http://erik-edgren.nu/textfile.php):

```
$url = 'http://erik-edgren.nu/files/history/apg29/jesus-september-2014.txt';
$lines = file($url, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

foreach($lines AS $line) {
    $info = explode(' - ', $line);

    if(strlen($info[0]) > '• ') {
        echo '<b>'.str_replace('• ', '', $info[0]).'</b>';
    }

    echo !isset($info[1]) ? '' : ' ('.$info[1].')';
    echo '<br>';
}
```

But I don't know how I can reformat the document as I want in the best way possible. Any solution on how I can accomplish this?

Comment: Does this work? Are you just trying to stream line the process?

Comment: my first approach would have been to read everything two lines at a time and explode on empty space. if first line does not begin with circle, move 2nd line into first one and read new 2nd line... but after looking at the data it seems that all you need is read things line by line, (explode on PHP_EOL), read first character and process stuff line by line accordingly.

Comment: @EricSSH: The code I provided works, as you can see on the webpage I linked to. Yes. I want to get the whole TXT file and reformat the content to show it on the website.

Comment: @Dimitri: Hm. Ok. The thing is that I don't know how I can accomplish that :/ I'm new in reformatting text files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the basic idea of what I would do. You probably need to replace '•' with unicode for that character.  This script does not probably work, but it has the general idea of what I would do.

```
<?php
$url = 'http://erik-edgren.nu/files/history/apg29/jesus-september-2014.txt';
$thedata=file_get_contents($url);
$lines=explode(PHP_EOL,$thedata);

 $line1='';
foreach($lines as $a)
{

    if(substr($a,2,2)=='• ')
    {
            $data=explode(' ',$a);
            $line1=$data[1] . ' (' . $data[3] . ' ' . $data[4] . ', ' . $data[5] . ')'.PHP_EOL;
    }
    if(substr($a,2,2)=='- ')
    {
    echo $line1 . substr($a,2) . PHP_EOL;
    }
}


?>
```

Comment: replace PHP_EOL with <br/> if you are displaying text on a page.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't make it work no matter how much I try to fix the problem :/ I've tested using the unicode version of • but that didn't change anything.